# Rock PBR Texture Creation within Blender (Procedural) for export in game engines

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I've seen in Blender Docs that there are some of the procedural textures in Blender like Voroni/Clouds/Noise etc.

### I've seen Substance Designer which is a good alternative to create textures for game assets/rendering. I wanted to ask if it's also possible to recreate Materials/Textures in Blender like Substance Designer?

I want to create a rock material like here -

[image: Rock Material]

with heavy Bump Detailing like here -

[image: Rock picture 2]

**Substance Designer just mixes textures/noises/patterns to generate materials, which I think is also possible in Blender.**

There are many tutorials to create a procedural rock over the internet, even one by Andrew Price, but they are of no use here, because I want to create a rock surface (not entire rock using Blender)

**From Rock Surface, I mean to create Displacement, Albedo and Normal Map which is fully procedural to create a rock which looks like the 1st image above**

**The first image of the Rock is what I want to recreate using Displacement, Albedo, and Normal Map**

Other tutorials/blogs/ Videos are not helping me because they are not the type of rock which I want to create. Also, they show how to make a rock using Displacement Map. I want the recreation of Displacement/Normal/Albedo map, both three, not only just creation of Rock!

What do I want to create? not a rock, but a rock material, because rock material can be used to create more and more shapes and sizes of rock with different Maps

- What type of rock I want to create?
  this type -

[image: What I wish to create]

not this -

[image: Andrew Price's Tutorial]

Can anyone show me a way to do this and please share the .blend file with the community?

Thanks :)

Ps - if you need any additional info or have any doubts regarding questions, just comment, I'll edit and provide additional info.

There are a lot of time lapse videos by designer which you can also use as reference while answering the question.

Comment: I downvoted this question, because it [shows no research](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I simple web search gives me plenty results and tutorials on procedural rocks in Blender and (Micro-)displacement. Do they not satisfy your needs? If not, why (illustrate)? There will be no **perfect** way applicable for every situation. Narrow down your field! (Games, Realtime, Still, Animation)

Comment: @Leander I've edited the Question Now. Hope this Helps :)

Comment: From experience I'm telling you if you want to use displace and export the model and the material to a game project, you do not want to use fully procedural textures. Like in this rock example something that looks good in the middle of the rock won't necessarily look good in the corner of the stone shape. What looks realistic on vertical surfaces doesn't look right on horizontal surfaces.Procedural material gets you 75% of the way but I recommend that you use UVs or weight painting to control it. Also using tileable textures within the procedural texture often gets things done faster.

Answer (score 2):

I worked ten minute or so and get these. I used two Voronoi for displacement, Clouds and Marble noise for surface diffuse and normal map. I doesn't look really good but you can create these blocky rockey surface like this using Volonoi as displacement map. But I really don't think it worth the effort...maybe you can do "Substance Designer" kind of things in blender, but blender is not specialized for these purpose. Unless you write custom plug-in for those kind of works, It's like digging your grave with a spoon.

[image]

[image]

[image]